# How can I use 'NIntegrate' to show the error?

Tags: numerics

I have to compute a very complicated integral, which is a 16-dimension one, so NIntegrate use Monte-Carlo.

I have set `Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo`, when I run NIntegrate for the first time, it gives one result something like `10^-30`, but run it again, something like `10^-50` will show up.

When I set `Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"` instead, a stable result shows up-- But it 'should' be stable because `quasiMC` uses constant series.

So, naturally I want to see the error of `NIntegrate`.

Thank you.

---

some images will be added below.

Note that:
1) In the second picture, I omit the Lorentz transformation which change the variables from p1, etc. to m12, etc..
2) In the last two images, I run the program without any change in the code--MC gave two completely different results!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If the integral is zero, then there's not much difference between `10^-30` and `10^-50`.  In any case, the way *M* estimates the error is described in [`tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Start by taking time to read the FAQ. This site is a collaborative effort, so don't only ask, but also give, by answering questions in your area of expertise. Also important, when you see good Q&A, upvote them, it shows appreciation. And accept the answer which best answers your question. Again, appreciation, but also a sign for others that the problem has been solved. Enjoy.

Comment: To Michael E2: In fact the integral is very close to 0, but not 0.

Comment: To Lou: I have tried to add and modify many parameters of NIntegrate, and I have read all the tutorial on NIntegrate that I can find. The integral is very very complicated from high-energy physics, Some time later I will post some code.

Comment: Your integral is analytically exactly zero since You have `Integrate[ Sin[theta1star] * whatever , {theta1star,0,2 Pi} , ..  ] `

Comment: oops, looking again the range of `theta1star ` is {0,Pi}, so it doesn't zero out, but still you can do that integration (and a couple of others) analytically first.

Comment: the round parenthesis under the square root in the integrand definition are a syntax error...please post actual code not a picture.